# In aws ec2, mongodb is not able to start

Tags: mongodb, nosql, ubuntu-16.04

I recently changed Instance type in AWS EC2 and since then mongoDB is not working.

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.14
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2019-01-16T10:46:38.525+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 
127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: 
Connection refused
2019-01-16T10:46:38.525+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't 
connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

mongod.log:

> 2019-01-16T09:21:17.579+0000 I -        [conn21] end connection
>   127.0.0.1:35148 (20 connections now open) 2019-01-16T09:21:17.579+0000 I -        [conn22] end connection 13.127.210.134:42626 (19
>   connections now open) 2019-01-16T09:21:17.579+0000 I -        [conn20]
>   end connection 127.0.0.1:35146 (18 connections now open)
>   2019-01-16T09:21:17.579+0000 I -        [conn19] end connection
>   13.127.210.134:42620 (17 connections now open) 2019-01-16T09:21:17.654+0000 I -        [conn18] AssertionException
>   handling request, closing client connection: 6 socket exception
>   [SEND_ERROR] for 127.0.0.1:35140 2019-01-16T09:21:17.655+0000 I -
>   [conn18] end connection 127.0.0.1:35140 (16 connections now open)
>   2019-01-16T09:21:19.408+0000 I ASIO
>   [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to
>   mdb2.thethingscloud.com:27017 2019-01-16T09:21:19.409+0000 I ASIO
>   [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to
>   mdb2.thethingscloud.com:27017 - HostUnreachable: Connection refused
>   2019-01-16T09:21:19.409+0000 I ASIO
>   [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections
>   to mdb2.thethingscloud.com:27017 due to failed operation on a
>   connection 2019-01-16T09:21:19.409+0000 I REPL
>   [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat re

Comment: What does the mongo server log say?

Comment: which command should I use for it?

Comment: `tail /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` maybe. thats the default log location.

Comment: I have edited the question adding log

Comment: how does the .conf file look are you binding your ip address correctly? Is there a node that is active perhaps on port 27017? and another which is shutdown ? The nodes don't like when they can't talk to each other ?  Also I found this solution some people say to "delete this file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"